# Poincaré's conjecture, revisited

Tags: general-topology

*Every simply connected, closed 3-manifold is homeomorphic to the 3-sphere.*

The above is a statement of  Poincaré's conjecture. But can I generalize this in the following way?

**If $\forall~n\in\mathbb{Z}\cap\left[2,\infty\right),$ every simply connected, closed *n*-manifold is homeomorphic to the *n*-sphere**

Maybe I should actually take a class or something in topology?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closed, simply connected manifolds which are not spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456664/closed-simply-connected-manifolds-which-are-not-spheres) The simpliest counterexample is $\mathbb{S}^n\times\mathbb{S}^m$.

Comment: The generalized Poincare conjecture is a bit different: every manifold homotopy equivalent to $n$-sphere is homeomorphic to $n$-sphere. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture

Comment: The (generalised) Poincare conjecture is also true for all $n\ge 4$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103182/poincare-conjecture-for-n-2).

Comment: The proposed duplicate does indeed answer your highlighted question in the negative. And yes, you should actually take a class or something in topology.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not true. $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is a closed manifold and is simply connected. It second homotopy group shows you that it is not the $4$-sphere (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space)).